# Find where is a border coming from

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap to create a layout on PhoneGap.

The with is 768px;

I have this simple HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="span12" style="background: red;">
<img src="img/teste.png">
</div>
</div>
```

I've place the red background just to check if the width is ok and it is.
Here is the image, with 768px;
[image]

And here is the damn left margin when I add a image:
[image]

I have checked both bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css for margin commands and nothing.

The image width is 768px (checked). I need to make the image fit the 768px.

Comment: Why don't you use the Inspector (right click, Inspect Element) to see what's going on?

Comment: thanks @EvanMulawski forgot about that and now I have noticed that when I add the image, it looks like the `bootstrap-responsive.css` is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That margin you see is part of the bootstrap grid system. It is there to fit the content properly wit the widths given in the bootstrap and its offsetted by the `.row` div, which you're not including in your markup.

So just encase your `.span12` div inside a `.row` div and it should be removed.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12" style="background: red;">
            <img src="img/teste.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: adding the row made the margin look a little smaller but still there. Using firebug I found that the CSS computed values are not ok, it is not calling the correct styles. On My header I have this meta `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` and the width been loaded is `711px`, don't know why

Comment: @Gerep add `img { width: 100%; height: auto; }` to your css to test if the image scales down on screen width.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-setting the margin and padding to zero

```
*{margin:0px;Padding:0px;}
```

Comment: same results...I think the `bootstrap-responsive.css` is not working when I add the image, don't know if it makes sense but when I add the image, the 768px width from `bootstrap-responsive.css` is not used